# gitlab inexplicably fails when it runs on local bash shell correctly

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Another Gitlab tear-your-hair-out-session. Have summarized the problem in it's simplest form.

Local script runs correctly

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

    echo $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE | grep "TO_DEV"   ; searchDEV=$? ; echo $searchDEV ;
    echo $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE | grep "TO_TEST"  ; searchTEST=$? ; echo $searchTEST ;
```

Output is

```
▶ CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE="jjj TO_DEV jjj" ./tst.sh 
jjj TO_DEV jjj
0
1
```

On Gitlab we have the following ....

```
setUp-Destination-job:
  image: localhost:6000/s3Bin/debian_slim_image:latest
  stage: build
  when: always
  script:
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE | grep "TO_DEV"   ; searchDEV=$? ; echo $searchDEV ;
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE | grep "TO_TEST"  ; searchTEST=$? ; echo $searchTEST ;
```

Gitlab stubbornly just does not do the same thing. It's running bash because the image has it. Been stuck here for 2 days. Worse still it's linter is really poor. And it just fails with "exit 1". No helpful error message or anything. Gitlab CI/CD is really poor with developer productivity. Why should any developer have to spend this much time to get this working ?

Unless, I have stumbled upon something really weird to do with $? being - ha! ha! clutching straws is what I have been reduced to. Because gitlab seems to find "TO_DEV" but has a problem even running "TO_TEST" - it should return the NOT_FOUND return code of 1. But, it does not !!!

```
$ echo $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE | grep "TO_DEV"   ; searchDEV=$? ; echo $searchDEV ;
xxx TO_DEV xxx using preBuildJob
0
$ echo $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE | grep "TO_TEST"  ; searchTEST=$? ; echo $searchTEST ;
Running after_script 00:01
Running after script...
$ echo "Hello from after_script:" ;
Hello from after_script:
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start by checking:

- the value of those variables:
- the same commands in a bash command.

So, first:

```yaml
- script:
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE | grep "TO_DEV"   ; searchDEV=$? ; echo $searchDEV ;
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE
```

Second:

```yaml
- script:
    - bash -c 'echo $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE | grep "TO_DEV"   ; searchDEV=$? ; echo $searchDEV ;'
```

Comment: Thanks for responding @VonC The value in $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE is supplied by the Gitlab Runner, and I have echoed in other parts so, it does get displayed. But, just to be sure I will do it in this cut-down example of mine and report back.

Comment: Also thought of the 2nd solution. Really, a bash script that works locally, same version, should be in a position to replicate the same results by Gitlab Runner conversion of my Yaml Script into a bash script.

Trying to double guess what Gitlab wants can be terribly unproductive. But, Thanks.

Comment: @user1561783 I agree. Those are just two suggestions to get some test going, in the hope to debug the current situation.